# Android notifiction dialogue picker how to reset tone

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am opening a notification tone picker dialogue whenever  I open it always show me all ringtone with default silent ringtone selected. How I can change selected ringtone i.e silent to some other ringtone.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question....

Comment: @BlackDevil sure 
What I am doing is I am opening notification ringtone picker on a button click it shows me a a dialogue with list of ringtone and check box in front of them to select any ringtone. whenever I open picker dialogue it always show all ringtone list and (silent ringtone is always selected or you can say the check box in front of silent ringtone is always checked). I want to change it to some other tone it should be decided on runtime.whenever I open the notification picker I can give a ringtone at run time to which it show selected . Hope I make some how clear to you

Comment: whenever I open dialogue last selected tone should be pre selected in the list .

Comment: When you show a dialog there will be a list. in getView method of adapter you can make it selected

Comment: Are you keeping the selected ringtone some where? If yes then when getView() is called you can chk for selected ringtone and set it there

Comment: notification dialog is of android it self ... we have to just call it  like sample code
Intent intent = new 'Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);'
'intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,RingtoneManager'.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);'
'intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Notification Tone");'
startactivityforrestul(intent);
I have nothing where i can modify the code .